# I have two folders of the same repo with diverging histories. How can I move one branch from folder B to folder A while still keeping history?

Tags: git, recovery

I have two folders of the same git repo but with diverging histories. How can I neatly transfer a branch from folder B to folder A?

My old computer broke down so I couldn't start it. I had one repo there with some changes in a branch I hadn't yet pushed. I cloned the new repo on another computer before I started backing up things and worked there.

I now have two folders of the same repo, after I managed to recover the old repo from my harddrive.

I see two potential fixes:

1. Start working on the recovered harddrive repo. There are a lot of changes in the new repo folder that I haven't pushed so it's still the same problem albeit less. My old repo also has a lot of local branches I do not want to keep, so I would prefer to do it in another way if possible.
2. Copy files from the branch I want and discard history

There should be a third one that is keeping the history of the branch in the B repo folder and also copying just the branch I want over to the A repo folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

In repo B (the one you want to extract a branch from)

```
git checkout branch-we-want-to-export
git format-patch --stdout origin/main > ~/whatever/branch-we-want-to-export.patch
```

In repo A (the one you want to import a branch into)

```
git checkout main && git pull && git checkout -b imported-branch-name
git am -3 < ~/whatever/branch-we-want-to-export.patch
```

Then if you get any conflicts you can fix them like usual merge conflicts and write `git am --continue` after you have fixed and `git add`ed them.